# JNI field id for static fields

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am currently trying to get the offset of a field in memory using JNI to be able to copy field values to off heap memory. I was able to get the offset for instance fields using the jFieldID for a field. The most significant 30 bits of a jFieldID represent the offset of a field for instance fields. The problem is with static fields. The 30 bits represent a JNIid*. A JNIid is a struct which contains an int offset field which is probably the offset of the field. Now my problem is how do I get this value. I used following code snippet (assuming id is the jFieldID of a field and address_shift is 2)

```
 uintptr_t result = (uintptr_t) id >> address_shift;
 // offset field in JNIid struc is in offset 16
 jlong staticFieldoffsetAddress = result + 16;
 jint* staticFieldValuePointer = (jint*) staticFieldoffsetAddress;
```

This however is not giving me any value. I get 0 which is not correct since I am comparing it with what I get from Unsafe.staticFieldOffset(Field) in java. I know I can call this method from JNI and use the result. But I want it for a performance critical application.

Comment: JNI provides functions for reading field values.  I strongly recommend that you use these instead of trying to reverse-engineer your particular JNI implementation.

Comment: yes, I know but I do not want to copy field values one by one. So I would like to get the minimum offset and the maximum and do a copy memory.

Comment: @MohamedOmer Why would you think that offset in memory won't ever change?

Comment: Why would the jvm change the offset in memory. I doubt that.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use GetStaticFieldID method?

```
public class Static {
    private static int field;

    private native void access();
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Static s = new Static();
        Static.field = 1;
        s.access();
    }
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Static");
    }
}
```

C source

```
#include "jni.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_Static_access(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    jfieldID fieldId;
    jint fieldValue;

    jclass class = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);

    fieldId = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env, class, "field", "I");
    if (fieldId == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    fieldValue = (*env)->GetStaticIntField(env, class, fieldId);
    printf("Value: %d\n", fieldValue);
}
```

Compile and run

```
> javac Static.java
> javah -jni Static
> cc -g -shared -fpic -I${JAVA_HOME}/include \
-I${JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin \
static.c -o libStatic.dylib
> java Static
Value: 1
```

Comment: BTW - you can find more JNI samples here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/

Comment: yes, I can get the value using JNI. But I would like to copy the values from memory. Imagine I have 10 static fields in a class. I do not want to copy them in a loop. I would like to get the min offset and max offset and then do a unsafe.copymemory to copy the values from min to (max + size)

Comment: What makes you think the fields are even sequential in memory to begin with? There are reasons why the JNI doesn't expose the raw memory address of fields. If you really need to read multiple values at a time, consider grouping them into an array first, and then access that instead. You can get a pointer to an array's data using `Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements()`, for instance.